# Installed Mongodb in wrong folder/directory...can I just move files to another folder?

Tags: mongodb, installation

I'm new to MongoDB.   I did my first install last week on a Linux machine and after I completed the install, I realized that I executed the install from the wrong folder/directory.  Can I just move the installed files in that folder to the correct desired location where I want MongoDB to reside?   I'm not familiar with all that happens during install, so I have no idea if install files are marked with an install home directory, or if other configurations occur that would result in MongoDB failing if I moved the files.   Any help appreciated...

Thanks

Comment: Off topic. You should rather ask http://www.serverfault.com

Comment: You can just delete the current installation and reinstall in the required directory. The data files will be kept wherever your `dbpath` was (default is `/data/db`.